# Showing that if a tensor is symmetric in one inertial frame, it is symmetric in all inertial frames

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor

I read that a tensor $U_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric if $U_{\mu\nu} = U_{\nu\mu}$, and that if a tensor is symmetric in one inertial frame, it is symmetric in all inertial frames. How can this be proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the tensor 
$$V_{\mu\nu} = U_{\mu\nu} - U_{\nu \mu}.$$
If $V_{\mu\nu}$ vanishes, then $U_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric, and vice versa.

If $U_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric in one frame, then $V_{\mu\nu}$ vanishes in that frame. But a tensor that vanishes in one frame vanishes in all frames, so $U_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric in all frames.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly compute

$$T'_{\alpha\beta}\pm T'_{\beta\alpha}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\alpha}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\beta}T_{\mu\nu}\pm \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\beta}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\alpha}T_{\mu\nu}$$
Or, renaming the dummy indices in the second term on the right hand side,
$$T'_{\alpha\beta}\pm T'_{\beta\alpha}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\alpha}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\beta}T_{\mu\nu}\pm \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\beta}\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\alpha}T_{\nu\mu}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\alpha}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\beta}\big(T_{\mu\nu}\pm T_{\nu\mu}\big)$$

Thus, we see that $$T'_{[\alpha\beta]}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\alpha}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\beta}T_{[\mu\nu]}$$
$$T'_{(\alpha\beta)}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\alpha}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\beta}T_{(\mu\nu)}$$

Thus, if the $T_{[\mu\nu]}$ is zero (or the $T_{(\mu\nu)}$ is zero) then it would remain so in all frames because a null tensor transforms to a null tensor universally. Or, in other words, a tensor would be symmetric (or anti-symmetric) in all frames or none.